# How to download files from db in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, web, phpmyadmin

I am creating a resource site for my campus where teachers upload files to folder and reference of that filed stored in db, and students can download those files using download option in student view side, and all these I have done in codeigniter using model view controller.

I need help for coding to download files. I managed to display a set of files but could not download yet, can anyone please help me with this? I'll be so thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$download_file = 'C:\example.zip';//path of the file
$content_type = mime_content_type($download_file);//mime type of the file
$file_name = basename($download_file);//file name 
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: ".$content_type);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($download_file));

    while (ob_get_level()) {
       ob_end_clean();
    }

readfile($download_file);
```

Comment: Thank you bharathi...I am using model view controller....is it controller code??....sorry I am a beginner...can u pls tell me according to model, view and controller code im codeigniter framewrk?

Comment: Why is header been used?

Comment: place it in controller

Comment: this is the response header that making the client browser to make the files to download...

Comment: Ok then? Way about model n view?? At present m displaying files on view bt cant download

Comment: Ok..then?wat bout model an view...? At present I have managed to display list of files on view bt cant download

Comment: you need to pass the file path as i mentioned in my answer

Comment: Thank you, ur code helped, sorry for late reply since i was since in stackoverflow as well